# Securing console application

Tags: .net, security

I am developing console which hooks to another process and send request to web api when certain event occurs in main application.

- To validate request to api HMAC Authentication is used, because login
  with password is not an option.
- I keep shared key value in protection section in app.config and
  retrieving it via SecureString.
- When there is no internet access all data is saved in encrypted file
  using CryptoStream

In my opinion this is not bad way to secure my aplication, but I am afraid this is not enough because users have access to .exe and admin privileges to local machine and they definitely will try to find how to hack my application.

What can I do to tighten the security even more? Or maybe you can advice others approaches?

Answer (score 3):

> users have access to .exe and admin privileges to local machine

Security-wise, you are doomed. You *cannot* secure something, that the attacker has root access to. There simply is no way. The only way is to restrict the user or move all your code to the server side leaving a hollow front end that basically calls the service for everything it does.

As an example:

> I keep shared key value in protection section in app.config and retrieving it via SecureString

What keeps the user from decompiling your app, inserting a line that shows the SecureString on the console, compiling *that* again and running it? Nothing, for they are root on the machine. There is no security for anything that is rooted already.

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt the communication with the API, if that is an option. Use HTTPS and certification for this. If you are afraid that the user may decompile your .exe, including some fake routines may help as well.

Can you specify what you are afraid that the user can do with the application?